# DocuSign connect

Tags: docusignapi

I do not know if I missed this information, but it seems to me that nowhere is written what the REST listener should return when it is called by the DocuSign connect.

Should it return a kind of formatted response?

Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign Connect will send an **HTTP** **POST** request to the endpoint that you specify for the Connect configuration settings.  When your "listener" application that resides at that endpoint receives a message from Connect, it will *automatically* respond via normal HTTP request/response semantics -- you shouldn't have to do anything (from a coding perspective) to make this happen, since it's just normal request/response behavior for a web application.

Comment: :) Of course... My question was about the response of my listener. Given that this is an HTTP post, my listener can reply something to give more information than the standard HTTP status. Is this necessary? Or the DocuSign connect expects an empty answer ?

Comment: That's not necessary. The listener will automatically respond, and the response it sends by default is sufficient to notify Connect that the message was successfully received.